# MySQL UPDATE ... WHERE ... IN (SELECT) inside trigger not updating values

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have created these 4 tables in mysql:

```sql
CREATE TABLE user(
     email VARCHAR(40),
     id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     username VARCHAR(30),
     password VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
     status ENUM('OK', 'possibleContact', 'covidCase') DEFAULT 'OK',
     lastUpdate TIMESTAMP DEFAULT NOW(),
     PRIMARY KEY(id, email)
)ENGINE = MyISAM;

CREATE TABLE POI( 
     id VARCHAR(50) PRIMARY KEY,
     name VARCHAR(130) NOT NULL, 
     address VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, 
     types TEXT,
     latitude FLOAT(20, 18) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
     longitude FLOAT(20, 18) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
     rating FLOAT(2,1) UNSIGNED DEFAULT 0,
     rating_n INT UNSIGNED DEFAULT 0,
     currentPopularity SMALLINT UNSIGNED DEFAULT 0,
     markerColor SET('Green', 'Orange', 'Red') DEFAULT 'GREEN',
     unsafeSince TIMESTAMP,
     unsafeUntil TIMESTAMP DEFAULT NULL,
     lastMarkerUpdate TIMESTAMP DEFAULT NOW(),
     covidCasesVisited INT UNSIGNED DEFAULT 0,
     spentTimeFrom SMALLINT UNSIGNED DEFAULT 0,
     spentTimeTo SMALLINT UNSIGNED DEFAULT 0
)ENGINE = MyISAM;


CREATE TABLE visit(
    idOfPOI VARCHAR(50),
    emailOfVisitor VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    timeOfVisit TIMESTAMP DEFAULT NOW(),
    estimatedNumOfVisitors INT UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(idOfPOI, emailOfVisitor),
    CONSTRAINT POIid FOREIGN KEY (idOfPOI)
    REFERENCES POI(id)
    ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE ,
    CONSTRAINT visitorIdentity FOREIGN KEY (emailOfVisitor)
    REFERENCES user(email)
    ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
)ENGINE = MyISAM;


CREATE TABLE covid19register(
    user_Id INT,
    lastUpdate TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY(user_Id, lastUpdate),
    CONSTRAINT caseRegistered FOREIGN KEY (user_Id)
    REFERENCES user(id)
    ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
)ENGINE = MyISAM;
```

And I want to create a trigger so, that when a new value is inserted in covid19register, all POIs that where visited by the user whose id got inserted in covid19register, would have its unsafeSince value updated to be equal to the lastUpdate field that was inserted. My solution doesn  't update the values though as expected. Here is what I 've written:

```sql
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS sickUser2;
DELIMITER $
CREATE TRIGGER sickUser2 
BEFORE INSERT ON covid19register
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN

UPDATE POI 
SET unsafeSince = NEW.lastUpdate 
WHERE POI.id IN (
    SELECT idOfPOI 
    FROM visit 
    INNER JOIN user as u ON emailOfVisitor = email 
    INNER JOIN covid19register ON u.id = user_Id);
 
END $
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: I do not see where the rows to be updated are correlated with currently inserted row' values. PS. I recommend you to add minimal sample data (as INSERT INTO scripts, 3-5 rows per table), then show `INSERT INTO covid19register` query and the changes which must be performed in `POI` by the trigger.

Answer (score 0):

it seems that you need in this:

```sql
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS sickUser2;

CREATE TRIGGER sickUser2 
BEFORE INSERT ON covid19register
FOR EACH ROW 
UPDATE POI
JOIN visit ON POI.id = visit.idOfPOI 
JOIN user ON visit.emailOfVisitor = user.email
SET POI.unsafeSince = NEW.lastUpdate 
WHERE user.id = NEW.user_Id;
```

Maximally simplified [DEMO fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=90d3dd0073ac47509bf83a6d21b20e96)

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Sadly, the result is the same as the trigger that I wrote. After inserting the values in covid19register, all POI.unsafeSince fields remain equal to NULL instead of being updated

Comment: @marioszap Demo fiddle added.